# Replacing words with php variables in a HTML text area

Tags: php, mysql

I have. Few forms using general HTML.

One form sends emails to contacts in a database.

How can i make it so when I use something like ##!CONTACT_FORENAME!## it will replace it with the contacts forename from the database (forename column in contacts table)

Comment: I think it is a [template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system) problem (see PHP `str_replace` or `preg_replace` functions)... but you must to explain better your problem: edit the question with fragments of HTML and/or PHP that you using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have template

```
$string_template = '
      Hello [username],
      .....
 ';
```

then you simple replace characters,

```
$message = strtr($template, array('[username]' => $user_name_from_dtb));
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i understand your question correctly but i would do something like this:

```
 <textarea><?php if (isset($var)) echo $var; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: I mean if I'm using the form to send an email to email addresses from a database if I typed in the body of the email ##!CONTACTS_FORENAME!## it would put the contacts forename in the email from the database

Answer (score 0):

```
$body='some text with [variable]';
$regex = "/\[.+?\]/"; // if not use brakets, change this.
if(preg_match_all($regex, $body, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $match) {
        $mvar=substr($match,1,strlen($match)-2); // get the variable name
        $value='this is a real value'; // get the variable value from db;
        $body=preg_replace("#\[".$mvar."\]#s",$value,$body);// replace 
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont use reg-exps when its not necessary :)